# Phonegap events not working in iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm having real trouble with PhoneGap in the iPhone with the events. The app is running pretty smooth in my android device, but on my iPhone it doesn't anything. For example, a simple code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WayAcross Mobile Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" />      
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="javascript/mainJavascript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Call onDeviceReady when PhoneGap is loaded.
            //
            // At this point, the document has loaded but phonegap.js has not.
            // When PhoneGap is loaded and talking with the native device,
            // it will call the event `deviceready`.
            //
            function onLoad(){
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }

            // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
                alert('ready');
            }

            </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascript/phonegap.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

(this is a code example that doesn't work with iPhone and works with android).

I think its a problem with the events, but I'm not sure. Even the code examples in PhoneGap docs don't work.
My environment is:

1. Mac OSX 10.7.1
2. Xcode 4.1
3. PhoneGap 1.1
4. jQuery Mobile 1.0RC
   The only thing that it shows me is this: http://cl.ly/0h462Y2D2F0J0B1B0q1M

Thanks in Advance.
Regards,
Elkas

---

By the way, I've installed OSX Lion 10.7.2 and Xcode 4.2 now. Even in the IOS5 its not working. This is driving me crazy!!!
Even with this simple code is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PhoneGap Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Call onDeviceReady when PhoneGap is loaded.
        //
        // At this point, the document has loaded but phonegap.js has not.
        // When PhoneGap is loaded and talking with the native device,
        // it will call the event `deviceready`.
        // 
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert('Hello World');
        }

        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascript/phonegap.js"</script>
</head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Everything looks okay there, try logging stuff using alert() to find out where it's failing.

Comment: Also try that. if I put onload="onDeviceReady()" in body tag or another function its showa the alert but the phonegap "events" still don't work. =(

Comment: jQuery mobile should be added *after* custom scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved!!

I run the application without the phonegap.js and it created me a new one. I just changed the name of it to the the one i was loading and the application finally works.

Comment: This is a great spot, had the same problem and couldn't work out what was going on. it's really not obvious the phonegap.js is generated per platform, you should clean up the question to make it easier what your problem was.

Comment: It's obvious if you actually look in the directories for your target platform of the phonegap download. You're supposed to put the platform-specific `phonegap.js` (or more recently `cordova.js`) into your `assets/www/` dir, and better to include it first.

Answer (score 1):

try putting the addevent listener under document.ready like this.. worked for me for the same problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){

},false);
});
```

Comment: ok. Let me try it and i'll give you an answer as soon as i'm at the office. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: ok, wait, will see my setup and tell u as soon as im in office tomo. :)

Answer (score 1):

When creating a Phonegap installation for iOS a specific version of the (ie) phonegap.1.4.1.js is used.

Replacing just this file with a newer version (like cordova.1.8.0.js) resulted in alerts not working.

If you want to upgrade to a newer Phonegap version you will have to "redo" your project.

I reverted back to phonegap.1.4.1.js and the events magically started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a wild guess here, not sure how you compile this thing into an app but you list XCode so.... The markup points to script files in folder jquery/ and javascript/. When compiling an app with XCode files are not placed in the actual folders that represent the group folders you normally use. In order for the files to actually end up in a directory inside the app you need to to add the folder on your harddrive as a folder reference (they show up as blue folders, not yellow).

The easiest way to check if this is the problem is to just remove the folder path of the script includes to just be the name of the file.

Comment: I know mate =) I've done that. Copy and reference folder. Here is a screen. http://cl.ly/2C243v0U2a0V062f2B0y

Answer (score 0):

```
function testDialog() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.notification.alert("This is message", function(){}, "HaHa", "Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.